# make UIScrollView's dragIcons more user friendly

Tags: c#, user-interface, uiscrollview, drag-and-drop, xamarin.ios

Regarding Monotouch C# iOS Development:

In one of my apps, I have a UIScrollview that acts as a "Toolbox" containing draggable icons.  The user can scroll through the toolbox deciding which item he wants, then drag it onto the screen.  It works fine and dandy, but the User Interface part could be improved upon.  I'd like to propose a method of improvement but I'm not sure how to go about implementing it.  Ideas?

[image]

The top of this image is the UIScrollview toolbox.  In it, there are several draggable icons.

**Current Method:**  UIScrollview contains draggable UIImages.  I'm using the scrollView.DelaysContentTouches = true method to transfer touches to the UIImage.  So basically, if the user swipes anywhere in the UIScrollview (even if he swipes on a draggable icon) as long as he swipes it quickly it counts as a scroll.  DelaysContentTouches has a built in delay of around 0.16 seconds.  Below is it's description for those who don't know:

**DelaysContentTouches:** If the value of this property is YES, the scroll view delays handling the touch-down gesture until it can determine if scrolling is the intent. If the value is NO , the scroll view immediately calls touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:. The default value is YES.

**Problems with Current Method:**  The current method works, but it's not idiot proof or super intuitive.  It is, to some degree, intuitive, but it's just not to my liking.  I've done some project demos with my software and the thing that people get tripped up on is trying to drag an icon from to toolbox.  They always try to drag in a "swipe-like-motion" and end up scrolling the toolbox instead of dragging the icon.  As stupid as that sounds, people who are new to the app ALWAYS spend about 1 minute trying to figure out how the drag works and I end up showing them that you have to touch and hold for a fraction of a second before you drag.  And that's not good.

**New Proposed Method:** My proposed method determines the user's intention of Dragging vs Scrolling based on the angle at which the "swipe" or "drag" is taking place.  I will define an angle range from the toolbox that is a Drag me Range, and a Scroll Me Range.  When the user Touches an icon and begins dragging it downward, the TouchesMoved function will measure the travel distance of the drag.  And once the Touch has traveled roughly 5 or 10 pixels in distance it measures the angle from initial touch location to the current traveled location.  If the angle is within the Drag Me Angle Range, it drags the icon.  If the angle is within the Scroll Me range, it scrolls the icon.

[image]

In this image, the red region on top is the "Scroll Me Range" and the yellow region down below is the "Drag Me Range".  THe angle is defined by the Yellow angled line.

**Implementing this New Method:**  How would I implement this?  Should I allow the Touch to go into the TouchesBegan of both the DragIcon and the UIScrollView, and then cancel the touch of whichever one it doesn't use?  Example:  User trys to drag an icon downward with a quick swipe.  Both the UIScrollView and the DragIcon receive a touch in TouchesBegan.  After it drags 10 pixels in distance a TouchesMoved function measures the angle and determines that it's within the DragMe range.  Because it's within the DragMe Range it cancels the touches within the UIScrollView so it no longer moves.... Can I do that?  The side effect here is that during that first 10 pixels of movement while it's waiting to measure the angle, both the DragIcon and the UIScrollview will be moving/scrolling...

How would you implement this?  Or do you have a better idea?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".